# How to convert TEXT column into an indexable field?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, mariadb

In order to optimize an app's performance, I'm trying to index fields which are frequently used in `WHERE` queries.
The database is `mariadb 10.3`.

One of those big culprits is a `msg` column which is of type `TEXT` so it can not be indexed:

```
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'msg' used in key specification without a key length
```

While the largest value is below, I don't mind if I need to truncate content of some of the `msg` rows to something like 2000 characters, if needed.

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(msg)) FROM msgs;
+------------------+
| MAX(LENGTH(msg)) |
+------------------+
|             2729 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.030 sec)
```

Well when I truncated large fields, and converted the field to `VARCHAR(2000)` and then tried to index it again, I get:

```
ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes.
```

Also, I can not make any changes to the app's codebase.

So I'm wondering what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: according to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/varchar/ varchar can hold up to 65535 characters, depending on your storage engine, there might also be a row limit

Comment: Add generated column which is any available hash of trimmed TEXT column value and index it. PS. What type(s) of condition(s) by this column may occur?

Comment: *Converting the column to VARCHAR is out of question, as it can hold only up to 256 characters.* This is limit for CHAR datatype. VARCHAR length limit is 64k-1.

Comment: Well when I convert the field to `varchar(2000)`, I get `ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `VARCHAR(2000)` can hold 2000 *characters*.
- A component of an index is limited to 3072 *bytes*.
- What is the `CHARACTER SET` for `msg`?  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE msgs`
- `CHARACTER SET utf8` treats a *character* as (up to) 3 *bytes* for the above computation.
- `utf8mb4` - 4 *bytes*.

But...  Why would you want to index a really long string?  Are you going to say things like

```
SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE msg = 'This is a very long message to make a point; blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah';
```

If you are going to use `FULLTEXT`, it does not have that limitation.

If you will use `LIKE` or `REGEXP`, OK.